# Выравнивание блока относительно input[range]

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scss

Пытаюсь добавить к input блок-подсказку, который будет перемещаться за ползунком.

Задача вроде бы тривиальная, но как только ползунок отклоняется от центра диапазона - блок-подсказка медленно уезжает по направлению движения...

Выравнивание относительно input происходит верно, блок-подсказка доходит ровно до его конца, но так как сам полузнок своими краями доходит только до края input'a - центрировать блок-подсказку относительно него не получается ( см. скриншот ).

Пробовал сделать самостоятельно с `position: absolute` и `position: relative`, гуглил примеры - результат один.

Скриншот проблемы: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93L76.jpg

Видео-демонстрация проблемы: https://youtu.be/zN9U2edzpQA

Разметка:

```js
function updateBonusElement(currency) {
  const bonusElem = document.querySelector("#bonus");
  const percent = (currency - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min);
  bonusElem.style.left = `${ percent }%`;
}
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  margin: calc(1vw + 3vh) 0 calc(1vw + 1vh) 0;
  border: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: calc(.1vw + .8vh);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: .3vh solid $accentColor;
  transform: scale(2);
}

.range {
  width: 70%;
}

.range>#bonus {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: calc(.3vw + .5vh) calc(1vw + .5vh);
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div className="range">
  <div id="bonus">
    <span className="accent">+{ bonus }</span> бонус
  </div>

  <input type="range" />
</div>
```

Comment: Почему в разметке `className`, когда должен быть `class` и откуда берётся переменная `range` в JS?

Comment: @De.Minov, это разметка react, судя по всему

Comment: @De.Minov верно выше ответили, это JSX Реактовский.

Comment: @De.Minov range - переменная компонента, которая контролирует настройки input'a. С вычислением процентов там проблем нет, на скриншоте и видео видно, что расчёты относительно input'a работают верно, проблема в ползунке.

Comment: По видео вижу, что позиционируется оно относительно самого ползунка, а не кнопки которой он двигается, отнимайте половину размера кнопки от ширины самого ползунка.

Comment: @De.Minov благодарю, думал, что размер кнопки тоже меняется вместе с высотой input'a - оказалось нет, нашёл фиксированное значение и поправил. Отправьте как ответ, помечу решением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По видео видно, что всё нормально работает, но подсказка позиционируется не относительно кнопки, а относительно элемента "по которому движется".

В качестве решения, могу предложить предложить при вычислении позиции вычислять от ширины элемента по которому движется кнопка, половину размера самой кнопки.
На глаз, по видео, но считаю что этого будет достаточно, при текущей вёрстке.